# Click em opção do checkbox desmarca as outras opções

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tenho um componente em vue que passo uma prop com as opções e ele gera um varios checkbox para min, oque preciso é que quando marcar a opção "nenhuma das alternativas" ele desmarque as outras alternativas caso elas estejam marcadas, e vice versa.
Meu componente agora:

```
 <template>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="mb-2" v-if="label">
      {{ label }}
    </label>
    <div class="form-check p-0" v-for="(option, index) in options" :key="index">
      <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          class="custom-control-input"
          :id="option"
          :value="option"
          v-model="checkeds"
        />
        <label class="custom-control-label" :for="option">{{ option }}</label>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-checkbox" v-show="error">{{ error }}</div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'CheckboxInput',
  $_veeValidate: {
    value () {
      return this.value
    },
    name () {
      return this.name
    }
  },
  props: ['label', 'name', 'value', 'validations', 'options', 'error'],
  watch: {
    checkeds (newValue) {
      this.$emit('input', newValue)
    }
  },
  data () {
    return {
      checkeds: []
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Igor, você quer que um _checkbox_ se comporte como _radio button_? Não seria mais fácil você usar _radio_?

Comment: Tambem pensei nisso, mas pelo requisito do projeto o usuário pode marcar 2 opções, por isso o radio não serve. é tipo: problema1, problema2, problema não informado, ele pode ter tido os 2 problemas

Comment: Entendi errado Igor, desculpa. Vou pensar em algo pra te ajudar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma maneira de você resolver seu problema é tratar a opção "Nenhuma alternativa" como uma opção especial. Ou seja, ela não estará incluída em `data.options` ou `data.checkeds` pois tem um comportamente especial.

A ideia básica e ter:

1. Um *array* de _strings com as opções (que já é o seu `prop` que você chama de `options`)
2. Um *array* de valores booleanos de mesmo tamanho que guardará o estado dos *checkbox* do seu componente.
3. Uma [*computed property*](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Properties) que retornará o estado do checkbox "Nenhuma alternativa". Ou seja, ela será verdadeira apenas se todos os *checkboxes* estiverem desmarcados.
4. Um método para "zerar" os *checkboxes*, ou seja, um método que atribuirá `false` para todos os valores do array que guarda os estados dos *checkboxes* (o item 2 desta lista).

Basicamente o que eu faço é guardar o estados (`checked`) em um *array* separado e tenho um método que atribui `false` para estes estados. A *computed property* serve apenas como um *feedback* visual para o usuário, ou seja, se nenhuma alternativa for marcada, a opção "Nenhuma opção" será `checked`, caso contrário ele será desmarcada.

Dito isso, o código a seguir faz exatamente o que a lista acima sugere. A única diferença é que eu executo o método que "zera" os *checkboxes* ao iniciar o componente, pois assim `data.checked` é iniciado com o mesmo número de elementos de `data.options`.

## Código

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: () => ({
        // Este array será dinâmico no componente pois será um prop
        options: ['Opção A', 'Opção B', 'Opção C'],
        // Deve ser iniciado com o mesmo tamanho de `options`
        checked: [],
    }),
    methods: {
        // Cria um array com N elementos de valor "false"
        resetChecked() {
            this.checked = Array(this.options.length).fill(false);
        }
    },
    computed: {
        // É true apenas se todos elementos de `checked` forem `false`
        nenhumaOpcao() {
            return this.checked.every(c => !c)
        }
    },
    // Inicia a variável `checked` ao montar o componente
    mounted() {
        this.resetChecked();
    }
})
```

```css
.label { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
    <h3>Opções</h3>
    
    <!-- Opções dinâmicas do componente -->
    <label v-for="(option, i) in options" class="label">
      <input type="checkbox" :checked="checked[i]" v-model="checked[i]">
      {{ option }}
    </label>
    
    <!-- Opção fixa "Nenhuma opção" -->
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" :checked="nenhumaOpcao" @click="resetChecked">
        Nenhuma opção
    </label>
</div>
```

---

### Extra

```
resetChecked() {
    // Cria um array com N elementos de valor "false"
    this.checked = Array(this.options.length).fill(false);
}
```

No código acima eu crio um método para "zerar" o _array _ `checked` usando o construtor de [Array](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array) e o método [`Array.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill).

O [construtor de Array](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array), quando recebe um inteiro como argumento, cria um array vazio de tamanho N. Exemplo:

```
let a = Array(3);
a[0];      // undefined
a[2];      // undefined
a[100];    // undefined
a.length;  // 3
```

Enquanto [`Array.fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/fill) preenche um array com o valor recebido. Eu uso este método juntamente com o método acima para criar um array com N valores `false` para usar no componente.

```
Array(5).fill(false); // [false, false, false, false, false]
Array(3).fill(0);     // [0, 0, 0]
```

Se [compatibilidade é um problema](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_array_fill) você pode usar outro método qualquer para criar um array. Exemplo:

```
function createArray(size, initial_value) {
    let new_array = [],
        i=0;

    for ( ; i < size ; i++) new_array.append(initial_value);

    return new_array;
}
```

---

```
nenhumaOpcao() {
    // É true apenas se todos elementos de `checked` forem false
    return this.checked.every(c => !c)
}
```

No código acima uso o método [`Array.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) para testar se todos os elementos de `checked` são `false`. É improvável que você tenha problemas de [compatibilidade](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mdn-javascript_builtins_array_every) com este método, mas para fins de estudo você poderia usar algo como:

```
function every(array, funcao) {
    for (let i=0, l=array.length ; i<l ; i++) {
        if (!funcao(array[i])) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, não tinha pensado nessa opção fixa, obrigado!